# Images not appearing properly when migrated from web server to local

Tags: 7, users, media, files

I copied all the files from my web-server to my local-host. Then i imported the databases as well. All functionality on the site works perfectly, but most of the images are breaking.

I tried opening any image on new browser tab, but i got an error: Error Generating Image.

I checked all the permissions and also the file path in admin/settings/filesystem and it set to sites/default/files.

Whenever i inspect any image i get the following address

```
 http://localhost/sites/default/files/styles/square_thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-177-1368495296.jpg
```

It looks fine but it shows **Error generating image**. Any suggestions.

Comment: Try comparing local settings with your on-line host. Do you use default php library for image styles (GD Library)?

Comment: File permission could be the problem. Check the file permission and update the same in local.